# Beamer - \spot not Transparent

Tags: beamer, highlighting, slideshow

In Beamer, I tried using `\spot`, but no matter what I tried, I couldn't get it to not be opaque.
e.g., If I write `\spot{0}: 1`, the spotlight 'highlights' `0`, but leaks over and hides `:` completely.
I want it to be half-transparent so if it leaks over another character, it is not completely hidden, i.e., you can still see `:`.
Ideally, I would like to make the spotlight yellow and half-transparent for the entire document.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: As always on this site, you are much more likely to get any help if you provide a small minimal self contained example that others can copy and test as is. This way others are much more likely to understand what you are talking about.

Comment: With the information given I can't reproduce the issue. Running `\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{spot}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Frame with spot}
some text \spot{0}: more text
\end{frame}
\end{document}` with PDFLaTeX (2 times) results in https://i.stack.imgur.com/5oLol.png, i.e., the `:` being visible. Could you check this example document and check whether it produces a different output?

Comment: For others, this is the `spot` package: https://ctan.org/pkg/spot

Comment: The [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer-contrib/spot/spot.pdf) for the `spot` package on page 2 suggests the use of something like `\setspotlightcolor{\spotlightcolor!50}` in case you disabled the fading of the background color using `path fading=none`.